# PHP and MySQL, get JSON data to feed HighCharts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I need to build a chart using Highcharts using PHP and MySQL.

From `data.php`, I get:

```
0: {categoria:Vendas, real:2038.00, orcamento:14000.00, desvio:-11962.00}
1: {categoria:Serviços, real:120.00, orcamento:8500.00, desvio:-8380.00}
2: {categoria:Outras, real:15000.00, orcamento:0.00, desvio:15000.00}
```

But, in order to build the chart, the data has to be in the following format:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Vendas', 'Serviços', 'Outras']

},
```

And:

```
series: [{
    name: 'orcamento',
    data: [14000, 8500, 0]
}, {
    name: 'real',
    data: [2038, 15000, 120]
}, {
    name: 'desvio',
    data: [-11962, -8380,15000]
}]
```

This is what I'm trying to do to convert the data in the right format and render the chart:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Anual'
        }
    };

    $.getJSON('data.php', function (data){
        $.each(data, function(key,value) {
            var series = [{}];
            var xAxis = [{}];

            if(key=='categoria'){
                options.xAxis.categories.push(value);
            }
            else{
                options.series.name.push(key);
                $.each(value, function(key,value){
                    //series.data=value;
                    options.series.data.push(value) 
                })
            }
        });
        //options.series[0].data=data;
        var chart= new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

The problem is that this code is returning the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined " on line:

```
options.series.name.push(key);
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Please see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

In options:

```
var options={
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Anual'
    }
};
```

You are missing properties for that object. For example: xAxis, series , series.data, series.names.